Struggling to Improve MSE in Forecast Model with RandomForestRegressor and XGBoost
I'd like to build a forecast model using RandomForestRegressor, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to improve my metric, which is MSE. I've also attempted XGBoost, but I'm getting the same result as with Random Forest. I'm really stuck here. Does anyone have any ideas? Normally, features don't require scaling in Random Forest, but I'm still trying to scale and train them now. It's time-consuming, and I don't have much time left. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
About dataset: Dataset include temperature, size of store, weekly_sales (as target), departments, store, sale_type and date
I tried random search and grid search on them
Grid_Search
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],            
    'max_depth': [10, 20, 30],                  
    'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],           
    'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4],              
    'max_features': ['sqrt', 'log2']               
}

rf = RandomForestRegressor()

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_


y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)

Random_Search
# Param Grid to Search 

param_dist = {
    'n_estimators': randint(100, 1000),  # Number of trees in the forest
    'max_features': ['sqrt', 'log2'],  # Allowed values for max_features
    'max_depth': randint(10, 50),         # Maximum number of levels in tree
    'min_samples_split': randint(2, 20),  # Minimum number of samples required to split a node
    'min_samples_leaf': randint(1, 20),   # Minimum number of samples required at each leaf node
    'bootstrap': [True, False]            # Method of selecting samples for training each tree
}

rf = RandomForestRegressor()

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_distributions=param_dist, n_iter=100,
                                   scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=5, random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)

random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)


best_params = random_search.best_params_

best_rf = random_search.best_estimator_
y_pred = best_rf.predict(X_test)

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print("Mean Squared Error (MSE):", mse)

rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
print("Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE):", rmse)

